# Events not visible in Event Log viewer

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log, eventviewer

Last weekend a server crashed, during the investigation I noticed that in the immediate run up to the failure we saw a large number of a specific event in the application log. In an attempt to understand what was occurring I attached a task to that event to send me an email if it occurred again.

I've been receiving emails all weekend, some 200 emails received since Friday evening, and they are still arriving.

This morning I've logged onto the server and opened event viewer and I cannot see any new instances of that event in the log viewer.

If i filter by event ID I can see the series of events from last week but nothing since then.

Get-Eventlog shows the same as the GUI viewer, ie no record of these events, and yet I am still getting the emails generated.

Everything else seems to be being logged as expected, as far as I can tell.

This is a Server 2008 R2 box runnin in an ESXi cluster, latest updates etc. Tools is up to date with ESXi (although I am going to move to 10.0.5 I think).

**EDIT:**
WEVTUTIL qe APPLICATION >>ApplicationLog.log

I can now see the logs triggering hte event. Still no idea why these are not showing in the viewer.

Comment: I suspect that whatever Windows process is sending those emails has them queued somewhere, and possibly because of a slow mailserver is taking a while? Have they stopped by now?

Comment: No, these are absolutely not queued. I'm still receiving them, some 27 received so far today. Mail server is capable of very high volume, and shows no queues. I am still convinced that these are still being generated by incidences of that event.

Comment: Don't the events have a timestamp associated with them? When were they generated? Why wouldn't you see them in the actual event logs? Are they coming from a standard log (e.g. Application, System) or from one of the newer Application/Services logs?

Comment: > Why wouldn't you see them in the actual event logs?

Yes, well thats what I'm asking isn't it, they aren't visible in event logs. As i say in the OP, these events were in the usual application log. Although I realise that they may be showing up in a different one, good point. I'll check now.

Comment: No, can't see the events in any other log either.

Comment: Odd. Can you post a screenshot of the email you are getting?

Comment: it won't tell you much, the email only contains details that I entered in the task scheduler configuration. Here's what my inbox looks like this morning thought : http://i.imgur.com/wrha6vD.png

Comment: I tried following this : https://vijredblog.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/task-scheduler-event-log-trigger-include-event-data-in-mail/ but could not get the amended XML to re-import back into task scheduler.

Comment: Stupid question, what happens if you disable the trigger? It definitely looks like there is something odd going on - the VMTools event that's being forwarded is normally only logged when a computer starts if I remember correctly?

Comment: well, the emails stopped coming through for an hour, then started again when I re-enabled the trigger. The event I'm seeing shouldn't ever trigger in an ideal world, but we saw a massive number before a recent crash so I was hoping to observe that happening again and catch any recurrence before it crashed.

Comment: What's the output of `WEVTUTIL GL Application`?

Comment: Can the events be forwarded to another server? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748890.aspx

Comment: Similar question I posted on SuperUser nearly 3 years later, except it is not for a server it is for Windows 10; EventLog items are being dropped off without me asking it to do so.. https://superuser.com/questions/1414698/does-windows-eventlog-drops-off-old-items-as-new-items-are-added

Answer (score -1):

It is most likely the Default setting for EventLog dropping off old items.

See my answer at:
https://superuser.com/questions/1414698/does-windows-eventlog-drops-off-old-items-as-new-items-are-added